# Always show image ALT-tag also when is empty

Tags: media

We are using [Media upload module](https://www.drupal.org/project/media). We are able to insert ALT text, while we are uploading the image.

But for the Web Guidelines, they want the ALT-tag always visible like `alt=""`. Also when it's empty!

[image]

How do I get this done?